# Tips for integrating $\int \frac{dx}{1+\cos(x)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

I tried the following
$$ 
\int \frac{dx}{1+\cos(x)}=\int \frac{1-\cos(x)}{1-\cos^2(x)}\,dx=
\int \frac{1-\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}\,dx\\
=\int \frac{1}{\sin^2(x)}\,dx-\int \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}\,dx=\int \csc^2x\,dx-\int \cot(x)\csc(x)\,dx
$$
Which I looked up and found to be equal to 
$$
\csc(x)-\cot(x)+c
$$

Do I need to memorize the final identity, or is there a more elegant way to evaluate this integral?

Comment: I think you should probably memorize the derivatives of trig functions. It helps that there are really only $3$. You probably know $\sin$ goes to $\cos$. Then $\sec$ goes to $\sec\ \tan$ and $\tan$ goes to $\sec^2$. Now if you have a co-something, then you just replace everything with its reciprocal and add a negative. For example "co-secant" goes to "negative co-secant c-tangent"

Comment: Looks like you figured out the tough part on your own.  It is worth memorizing that $\frac {d}{dx} \tan x = \sec^2 x$  If you know that, you know that $\int \csc^2 x dx $ is something similar... or, $\int \csc^2 x dx  = \int \sec^2 (\pi/2 -x) dx , \int \frac{\cos x}{\sin^2 x} dx $ you could tackle with a $u = \sin x$ substitution.

Comment: @DougM Got it. Thanks for deriving the $csc^2$ integral too, that was cool.

Comment: @ElliotG Ah I hadn't realized I could remember the co identities that way. Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do the substitution $x=2u$. $$\int \frac{dx}{1+\cos(x)} = 2\int \frac{du}{1+\cos(2u)} = \int \frac{du}{\cos^2(u)} = \tan(u)+C = \tan(x/2)+C.$$

Comment: Ah thank you, I didn't see this.

Comment: The other trick in this nice solution is recognizing that $(1+\cos 2u)/2 = \cos^2 u$.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two methodologies that provide a way forward.

> **METHODOLOGY $1$**  **Classical [Weierstrass Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution)**

In this classical and systematic approach, we enforce the substitution $u=\tan(x/2)$.

Then, using $\cos(x)=\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}$ and $dx=\frac{2}{1+u^2}\,du$ we find

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{1+\cos(x)}\,dx&=\int \frac{2}{(1+u^2)+(1-u^2)}\,du\\\\
&=u+C\\\\
&=\tan(x/2)+C
\end{align}$$

as expected!

---

> **METHODOLOGY $2$**  **Use of Complex Analysis**

Note that we can express the cosine function as $\cos(x)=\frac12(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{1+\cos(x)}\,dx&=\int \frac{2}{(e^{ix/2}+e^{-ix/2})^2}\,du\\\\
&=\int \frac{2e^{ix}}{(e^{ix}+1)^2}\\\\
&=\frac{2i}{(e^{ix}+1)}+C\\\\
&=\frac{2ie^{-ix/2}}{e^{ix/2}+e^{-ix/2}}+C\\\\
&=\tan(x/2)+i+C\\\\
&=\tan(x/2)+C'
\end{align}$$

As was to be shown!

---

> **EXTRA**

Here we show that $\csc(x)-\cot(x)=\tan(x/2)$.  We proceed by writing

$$\csc(x)-\cot(x)=\frac{1-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$$

Next, we invoke the identities $1-\cos(x)=2\sin^2(x/2)$ and $\sin(x)=2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)$.  Therefore, we have

$$\frac{1-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}=\frac{2\sin^2(x/2)}{2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)}=\tan(x/2)$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: One should note that although Stewart's calculus textbook attribute the tangent half-angle substitution to Weierstrass, that is almost certainly wrong and Stewart told me in an email that he wrote that only because it was a conventional name, not because he knew the history. It was used by Euler before Weierstrass was born.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Good comment.

Answer (score 4):

The usual tables of derivatives tell you that
$$
\frac d {dx} \csc x = -\csc x \cot x
$$
and
$$
\frac d {dx} \cot x = -\csc^2 x
$$
so if you've got those, then you're almost done.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method similar to C. Dubussy's solution except no substitution needs to be made.

Recalling $1 = \cos^2 \frac{x}{2} + \sin^2 \frac{x}{2}$ and $\cos x = \cos^2 \frac{x}{2} - \sin^2 \frac{x}{2}$, the integral may be written as
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{dx}{1 + \cos x} &= \int \frac{dx}{\left (\cos^2 \frac{x}{2} + \sin^2 \frac{x}{2}\right ) + \left (\cos^2 \frac{x}{2} - \sin^2 \frac{x}{2} \right )}\\
&= \int \frac{dx}{2 \cos^2 \frac{x}{2}}\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int \sec^2 \frac{x}{2} \, dx\\
&= \tan \frac{x}{2} + \cal{C}
\end{align*}